# Data not populating in firebase while using redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I have created a collection called categories in the firebase database and I am trying to get the values from there.

[image]

I am calling the function in Home fragments in my app through `componentDidMount` function.

I am connecting the Homefragment here with `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.

Here is my HomeFragments.js

```
export class HomeFragment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: 0,
    };
  }

  handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    this.setState({
      value: newValue,
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.categories === null) {
      this.props.loadCategories();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container maxWidth="md" fixed>
        <AppBar position="static" color="white">
          <Tabs
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
            variant="scrollable"
            scrollButtons="auto"
            aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
          >
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
            <Tab icon={<CategoryTab />} />
          </Tabs>
        </AppBar>
        <BannerSlider
          Images={[{ image: "https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" }]}
        />
        <HorizontalScroller />
        <StripAdView />
        <GridView />
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export const CategoryTab = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Avatar
        alt="Remy Sharp"
        variant="square"
        src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
      />
      <Typography variant="body2">Title</Typography>
    </Box>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    categories: state.categories,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    loadCategories: () => dispatch(loadCategories()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeFragment);
```

I am calling the method in categoryAction.js:

I am using `loadCategories` to try to load the categories from my firestore. Ideally it should take all the value from my collection of categories in my firestore and load it into `querySnapshot`

```
export const loadCategories = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    firestore
      .collection("CATEGORIES")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log("querysnapshot:", querySnapshot);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};
```

In this I am calling a `console.log(querySnapshot)` which should give me the value in the console. However I am not getting any value in the console.

Here is my App.js:

```
const DEFAULT_REDUCER = (initstate, action) => {
  return {
    key: "HELLOW WORLD",
  };
};

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    DEFAULT: DEFAULT_REDUCER,
    categories: categoryReducer,
  })
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Authenticated>
            <Dashboard />
          </Authenticated>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/login">
          <Authenticated nonAuthenticated={true}>
            <Login />
          </Authenticated>
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" render={() => "404 Not Found!"} />
      </Switch>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong and why am I not getting the value can somebody help?

Comment: Did the answer by @BittorH solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling

```
firestore.collection("CATEGORIES").get()
```

instead of

```
firebase.firestore().collection("CATEGORIES").get()
```

Your `loadCategories` method should look like this

```
export const loadCategories = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    firebase.firestore()
      .collection("CATEGORIES")
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log("querysnapshot:", querySnapshot);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: no data populated later with the same code

Comment: Can you specify what is the current problem you are facing with Firebase?